# c++ error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I have an error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token. I am not sure what it is expecting as it seems fine but clearly is not.  Thanks, All

**Here is the error**

```
account.cpp:16:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 account::acct(num, int_balance) {
              ^
account.cpp:22:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 account::deposit(amount) {
```

**Header file**

```
//account.h

#ifndef account_h_
#define account_h_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class account
{
public:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account
    int acct(int num, float int_balance);
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int account_num() const {
        return acctnum;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //constructs bank account with inital_balance
    double balance() const {
        return bal;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //deposit into account
    void deposit(float amount) {
        bal += amount;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //withdrawal from account
    void withdraw(float amount) {
        amount - bal;
    }
private:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int acctnum;
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //balance
    double bal;
};

#endif
```

**program file**

```
//account.cpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "account.h"

//----------------------------------------------------
//Account details
account::acct(num, int_balance) {
    acctnum = num;
    bal = int_balance;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Depositing into account
account::deposit(amount) {
    if (amount < 0) {
        std::cout << endl <<"The deposit you've enter is negative." 
        << amount << " on account " << acctnum << endl;
    }
    else {
        balance = amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Withdrawing from account
//If withdrawel exceeds balance provide error and leave balance
//Else subtract withdrawel from account and update balance
account::withdraw(amount) {
    if (amount < balance) {
        std::cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance." 
        << amount << " on account "<< acctnum << " with balance "
        << balance << endl;
    }
    else if(amount < 0) {
        std::cout <<"The withdrawel you've enter is defined as negative." 
        << amount << " on account "<< acctnum << " with balance "
        << balance << endl;
    }
    else {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Insert intial balance of account
//If no balance included then give error message and set account balance to 0
account::int_balance(float amount){
    if (amount >= 0) {
        balance = amount;
    }
    else {
        balance = 0;
        std::cout << "Error intial balance invalid" << endl;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
account::balance(){
    return bal;
}
```

Comment: In the first declaration `acct()` returns `int`.

Comment: Is `account::acct` supposed to be the constructor? Why are you *defining* some member function multiple times? Why don't you supply the return types in the source file? Why don't you supply argument types in the source file? Maybe you should check [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and find a good beginners book?

Comment: You are missing  a type there. It needs to be `account::acct(int num, int_balance) {`

Answer (score 3):

In your function implementation you forgot to specify the types of the paramters:

For example

`account::acct(num, int_balance) {`

should be

`account::acct(int num, float int_balance) {`

Btw: account::acct is not a constructor. The constructor must have the same name as the class and must not have a return value.